# Understanding and tracking of metrics in object detection

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, metrics, object-detection, tensorboard

I have some questions about metrics if I do some training or evaluation on my own dataset. I am still new to this topic and just experimented with tensorflow and googles object detection api and tensorboard...

So I did all this stuff to get things up and running with the object detection api and trained on some images and did some eval on other images.

So I decided to use the weighted PASCAL metrics set for evaluation:
And in tensorboard I get some IoU for every class and also mAP and thats fine to see and now comes the questions.

The IoU gives me the value of how well the overlapping of ground-truth and predictes boxes is and measures the accuracy of my object detector.

**First Question**: Is there a influencing to IoU if a object with ground-truth is not detected?

**Second Question:** Is there a influencing of IoU if a ground-truth object is predicted false negativ?

**Third Question:** What about False Positves where are no ground-truth objects?

**Coding Questions:**

**Fourth Question:** Has anyone modified the evaluation workflow from the object detection API to bring in more metrics like accuracy or TP/FP/TN/FN? And if so can provide me some code with explanation or a tutorial you used - that would be awesome!

**Fifth Question:** If I will monitor some overfitting and take 30% of my 70% traindata and do some evaluation, which parameter shows me that there is some overfitting on my dataset?

Maybe those question are newbie questions or I just have to read and understand more - I dont know - so your help to understand more is appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: what's the difference between 1 and 2 ? A true object that does not get detected is a false negative... 3. If there is no ground-truth object, then it is a False positive, not a True positive.  4. You say in the beginning that you already have accuracy, and here you say you don't...

Comment: Q2 does have a predicted box and is overlaying the ground-truth box but with a false negative prediction and Q1 does not have a predicted box so there is maybe a lowering in IoU!? To Q3 jep and corrected! I just said that the IoU measures the accuracy of an object detector but the value is just how well the predicted box overlays the ground-truth

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with defining **precision** with respect to a particular object class: its a proportion of good predictions to all predictions of that class, i.e., its TP / (TP + FP). E.g., if you have dog, cat and bird detector, the dog-precision would be number of correctly marked dogs over all predictions marked as dog (i.e., including false detections).

To calculate the precision, you need to decide if each detected box is TP or FP. To do this you may use **IuO** measure, i.e., if there is significant (e.g., 50% *) overlap of the detected box with some ground truth box, its TP if both boxes are of the same class, otherwise its FP (if the detection is not matched to any box its also FP).

* thats where the @0.5IUO shortcut comes from, you may have spotted it in the Tensorboard in titles of the graphs with PASCAL metrics.

If the estimator outputs some quality measure (or even probability), you may decide to drop all detections with quality below some threshold. Usually, the estimators are trained to output value between 0 and 1. By changing the threshold you may tune the recall metric of your estimator (the proportion of correctly discovered objects). Lowering the threshold increases the recall (but decreases precision) and vice versa. The **average precision (AP)** is the average of class predictions calculated over different thresholds, in PASCAL metrics the thresholds are from range [0, 0.1, ... , 1], i.e., its average of precision values for different recall levels. Its an attempt to capture characteristics of the detector in a single number.

The **mean average precision** is mean of **average previsions** over all classes. E.g., for our dog, cat, bird detector it would be (dog_AP + cat_AP + bird_AP)/3.

More rigorous definitions could be found in the PASCAL challenge [paper](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/postscript/ijcv_voc09.pdf), section 4.2.

Regarding your question about overfitting, there could be several indicators of it, one could be, that AP/mAP metrics calculated on the independent test/validation set begin to drop while the loss still decreases.

Comment: Ok - I understand and know that if an IoU has an value greater 0.5 and the detected box is of the same class as ground-truth box that it is TP. But it is lowering the IoU if one ground-truth box has no predicted box? And what if I have a good IoU on my eval test set and I see there is a predicted box with no ground-truth box a so called FP? What if the last mentioned comes in do I have to train more on my set or what does this mean?

Comment: Yes, predicted box without a matching ground truth box lowers the precision measure. If you have lot of such cases in your evaluation you may try to add more images that do not contain the object into the training set.